# How do I earn the achievement "The Silencer - Destroy flare weak point to interrupt a ship from firing flares."?

Tags: achievements, skull-and-bones

I'd like to know what specific part of the enemy ship to aim for. Is it highlighted in red as a weakpoint? Any recommendations which weapons to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No they are not hilighted in red as weakpoints, according to [this guide](https://game8.co/games/Skull-and-Bones/archives/445171):

> Destroying the enemy ship's flares will deal additional damage and will stop them from calling reinforcements. Many players may overlook this since the ship flares are **not highlighted as a weak point** during battle.

Additionally:

> Based on observation, enemy ships will start lighting up flares to call for reinforcements once they're nearly destroyed. It takes about 30 seconds before the flares are launched, giving you ample time to destroy the flares or the ship itself.
>
> The time before the flares are launched to call for reinforcements may vary from ship to ship.

There is a short video in the guide demonstrating this.